# AlamofireImage Usage

Tags: ios, swift, alamofireimage

I'm trying to understand the way to use [AlamofireImage][1]

i have a few questions:

1. when i use:

`Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/image/png").responseImage { response in
    if let image = response.result.value {
        //Do Somthing
    }
}`

is that all i need to do to use swift native URLCache?
Does it caching it automatically?

2. after the first request above, can i use AlamofiremImage fetch method?

   // Fetch

   ```
   let cachedImage = imageCache.image(withIdentifier: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")
   ```

or do i have to use URLCache cachedResponse(for: URLRequest) method?

3. (if the answer to 2 is "no") Do i need to actively save the image cache with alamfireImage Add method after the request response?

   // Add

   ```
   imageCache.add(image, withIdentifier: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")
   ```

(with relation to question 1) isn't it creating additional cache to the same image and url (once with URLCache and another with AlamofireImage add method)?

thanks!